# "if let" vs "unwrap_or_else" for callback call

Tags: rust, callback

Can anyone explain why this Rust code compiles just fine :

```
if let Err(why) = match cmd.name {
    "info" => info,
    "ping" => ping,
    "profile" => profile,
    _ => panic!(),
}(&ctx, &cmd)
.await
{
    println!("An error occured while handling command: {}", why);
}
```

...but this code won't (the compiler says that I need to use a semicolon after closing the match block) :

```
match cmd.name {
    "info" => info,
    "ping" => ping,
    "profile" => profile,
    _ => panic!(),
}
(&ctx, &cmd)
    .await
    .unwrap_or_else(|why| println!("An error occured while handling command: {}", why))
```

The only solution I found is to use a temporary variable to store the callback prior to calling it but I don't understand why that's only necessary in the second code sample :

```
let callback = match cmd.name {
    "info" => info,
    "ping" => ping,
    "profile" => profile,
    _ => panic!(),
};
callback(&ctx, &cmd)
    .await
    .unwrap_or_else(|why| println!("An error occured while handling command: {}", why))
```

I suspect it's linked to the declaration vs expression thing but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Have you tried `(match cmd.name { ... })(&ctx, &cmd)`? Also, the closure passed to `unwrap_or_else` must return the same type as `Ok`.

Comment: @PitaJ it actually works, but do you know why? (operator precedence?)

Comment: @prog-fh I believe it's because the match statement is considered an expression when it's on the right hand side of an assignment. But when directly using the value, the Rust parser needs to know for sure that the match is an expression before you immediately invoke it. Aka why the parens make the compiler happy.

Comment: I think there's more accurate information here: http://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/reference/expressions.html#place-expressions-and-value-expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/statements.html#expression-statements

> An expression that consists of only a [block expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/block-expr.html) or control flow expression, if used in a context where a statement is permitted, can omit the trailing semicolon. This can cause an ambiguity between it being parsed as a standalone statement and as a part of another expression; in this case, it is parsed as a statement. The type of [*ExpressionWithBlock*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions.html) expressions when used as statements must be the unit type.

`match` is a control flow expression, and what you're seeing is the ambiguity described above. Because it is compiled as a statement its type is expected to be `()`, and that is the reason for the error you saw.